# Factoring maps through quotient set

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying *Topology: An Introduction with Application to Topological Groups*, by McCarty.  In Chapter IV (pg 102) he makes the following claim:

> Let $p: \mathbf{I} \to X$ be a path in a space $X$ with $p(0) = p(1)$; that is, $p$ is a "closed path," which begins and ends at the same place, a "loop" in $X$.  Then $p$ is constant on each equivalence class of the quotient map of the interval $\mathbf{I}$ into the circle $S^1$ which identifies the end points of $\mathbf{I}$, and there obviously exists a unique function $g: S^1 \to X$ such that $g \circ q = p.$  It is natural to hope that $g$ is continuous, that a closed path in $X$ corresponds uniquely to a map of $S^1$ into $X$.  It does.

I cannot understand this uniqueness aspect.  I have two competing, seemingly wrong interpretations of his words:

- $S^1 = \{ (\cos x, \sin x) \mid x \in [0, 2 \pi] \}$ is "the unit circle in the plane" as stated a couple pages earlier.  I can map $\mathbf{I} = [0,1]$ to $S^1$, identifying $0$ and $1$ in $\mathbf{I}$ as the same point.  Then if $h: \mathbf{I} \to S^1$ is suitable, there exists a continuous $g: S^1 \to X$ such that $p = g \circ h$.  Given a fixed $h$, $g$ must be unique.  But this seems like a weaker claim than "a closed path in $X$ corresponds uniquely to a map of $S^1$ into $X$," because it depends on a choice of $h$.
- $S^1 = \mathbf{I}/R$ where $R$ is the equivalence relation that identifies $0$ and $1$ in $\mathbf{I} = [0,1]$.  Since $S^1$ and the quotient function $q: \mathbf{I} \to S^1$ is uniquely defined by $R$, there is a unique $g: S^1 \to X$ such that $g \circ q = p$.  But I don't think $S^1$ is a quotient space—I think $S^1$ is a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  He calls $S^1$ the "unit circle in the plane."

McCarty wraps up the section by stating

> Now it is evident that a map $f: S \to T$ has a factoring $f = g \circ q$ through $S/R$, where the factor $g$ is a map, iff $f$ can be factored through $S/R$ as a function... This result means... that there is a 1-1 correspondence between the set of all maps of $S^1$ into a space $X$ and the set of those maps of $\mathbf{I}$ into $X$ which begin and end at the same point...

(Here, $S$ and $T$ are spaces and $R$ is an equivalence relation.)  How do I interpret $S^1$ to make this make sense?  Is it a quotient space (a set of equivalence classes of points in $[0,1]$) or is it a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, or is something else going on?

Comment: In topology, most of the time one cares only about spaces up to homeomorphism. The unit circle in the plane is just one specific incarnation of $S^1$. It is homeomorphic to $I/R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is clearly what the author intends:

Define an equivalence relation on $[0,1]$ with classes $\{0,1\}, \{x\}, 0 < x < 1$, so the only non-trivial equivalence class is $\{0,1\}$ (identifying the endpoints of $I=[0,1]$). Let $q: [0,1]\to [0,1]{/}R$ be the quotient map and note that it's a pretty standard fact that the latter quotient is homeomorphic to $S^1$ (one homeomorphism $h: [0,1]/{R} \to S^1$ is $h([x])=(\cos(2\pi x), \sin(2\pi x))$ e.g.)

Now having $p:[0,1] \to X$, the closed loop from the beginning, we want $g: [0,1]{/}R \to X$ so that $g \circ q= p$. So we have *no choice*. If $[x]$ is some class in $[0,1]{/}R$ then $[x]=q(x)$ by definition, so we know what $g([x])=g(q(x)) = (g \circ q)(x)$ **has to** be: $p(x)$ by the identity $g \circ q = p$.

So the unicity of $g$ is clear. But is it well-defined? This too is quite clear in this case: $[x] = \{x\}$ in almost all cases so there is no choice involved in writing $[x]=q(x)$. But in the *one* case $[x]=[0]=[1]= \{0,1\}$ we have that we could write both $q(0)=[x]$ *and* $q(1)= [x]$ and then $g([x])$ must equal $p(0)$ in the former case and $p(1)$ if we make the second choice. But **by assumption** we actually have $p(0)=p(1)$ and however we had chosen, $g$ has a single value. So $g$ is indeed a well-defined function on *all* classes that obeys $g \circ q = p$ always.

The fact that we *have* some homeomorphism between $[0,1]{/}R$ and $S^1 \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ allows us to call the quotient space "the circle in the plane" even though literally it is not (it's a set of classes), but **topologically** it is.

Finally, the identity $g \circ q= p$ allows us to say that $g$ is continuous whenever $p$ is by a standard property of quotient topologies. (of course $[0,1]{/}R$ gets the quotient topology and it's in that topology it is homeomorphic to $S^1$).